# How to create .github/workflows in my Github Repository?

Tags: github

I create this folder in browser , it works but finally I see 2 folders created

```
.github
  workflows
```

but I need .github/workflows as described it the documentation.
I cannot rename it now.
How to create .github/workflows folder?